# Why does the on mouse in even gets triggered when the mouse is not in the button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, mouseevent

I have a start button in my js game. I just noticed that I can be slightly to the right of it, and the cursor is a pointer. My css:

```
#start{
position: absolute;

top: 130px;
left: 195px;
height: 80px;
width:320px;

background-color: red;

cursor: pointer;

border: 2px solid yellow;
border-radius: 20px;
}
```

The button is just a div. After setting the button to a variable named "start", I use the following js to make it change background on hover:

```
start.onmouseover=function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor="#FF4500";
}
start.onmouseout=function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

I am able to trigger the hover by being outside of the button. Why is that? [Here](http://solonkojsgame.net16.net/game.js) is the game where the issue occurs. The button is the first thing you see. This occurs with some other buttons as well. I know that I can use css hover, but am curious to find out what's wrong with this.

Comment: FYI - no need for javascript to change hover styles...use css `:hover` selector

Comment: In my description I wrote that I am aware of that @charlietfl. I guess that would be a better approach and that is what I will do. I just asked this because of curiosity why it acts weirdly.

Comment: No way for us to know without a demo that replicates it

Comment: Which browser are you using? Maybe isolating it in a JSFiddle would help

Comment: I am using chrome. You can see the issue by going to the link.

Comment: I used JSFiddle and found out that it is the styling of the text inside. If I make margin 0, it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is acting this way can be found in your css for `#new`:

```
#new {
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
color: yellow;
position: relative;
left: 48px;
bottom: 24px;
```

You should note that this child component is inheriting the width of the parent div which you set to have a width of 320px. You can verify this by inspecting the parent and child and looking at the computed styles:

Parent:
[image: Parent element]

Child: 
[image: Child element]

Then in your css for `#new`, you MOVED the position of the element to the right by 48px:

`left: 48px;`

This element still has a width of 320px as shown in chrome developer tools.

[image: Leaked Child]

I bet that little blue bit that has overflowed is exactly 48px and where you are experiencing that unwanted behavior =) So, I hope you now understand what is going on with your css!

You can even verify this by setting the width of the child to be:

`width: calc(100% - 48px);`

You should find now that there is no more overflow:

[image: No more overflow]

Answer (score 1):

The browser is actually taking the hover-detection from this area here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDkYr.png

You can probably see that it uses the text as the start of the hover area, and that there's a lot of padding on the right of the element. You'll want to remove this padding using CSS.